# DTS Script task encountered exception in user code -client.Send(mail)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, script-task

I have a script task to send an email on some data statistics sourcing the date from  a view and it was all working fine until last week  however suddenly without any modifications to the code, the script task  suddenly now crashes with the error ' DTS script task encountered an exception with the user code' just before the statement client.Send(mail) in the code (C#) and I'm not able to figure out what may be causing this issue. Can someone please help me . Thanks

I have created a new script task copying the code however it still fails with the same error. 
Im using VS 2015.

Comment: There was probably a modification to the server it runs on, i.e. the mail library is no longer installed or accessible. Best thing to do is add additional error handling to the script to capture a more useful error message.

Comment: Either waht Nick says, or similar vain, just get the package, download it from server (or take your local version) open the script, recompile it, and then upload to server again  This has happened to us a few times, you need to just recompile sometimes, or may need to add new/different reference like Nick suggests.

Comment: Thanks for you responses. As Nick suggested , I have tried recompling the package many time but still no luck. Can you please elaborate a bit more on how to add a new/different reference. Thanks